Estimating simple regression scaling parameter with the characteristic function
For the characteristic function we have:
$$\phi_Y(t) = \phi_X(at)$$
where $Y=aX$. Expanding this out we have,
\begin{align}
\int f_Y(y) e^{ity}dy &= \int f_{aX}(ax)e^{itax} dx = \int f_X(x) e^{itax} dx \\
\frac{d}{dt} \int f_Y(y) e^{ity}dy &= \frac{d}{dt} \int f_X(x) e^{itax} dx \\
i\int y f_Y(y) e^{ity}dy &= ia \int x f_X(x) e^{itax} dx \\
\int\int x'y f_Y(y) e^{it(y-ax')} dydx' &= a \int \int xx' f_X(x) e^{ita(x-x')} dxdx' \\
\int\int x'y f_Y(y) \int e^{it(y-ax')}dt dydx' &= a \int \int xx' f_X(x) \int e^{ita(x-x')} dtdxdx' \\
\int\int x'y f_Y(y) \delta(y-ax') dydx' &= a \int \int xx' f_X(x) \delta(a(x-x')) dxdx' \\
\int\int xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) dydx &= a \int \int xx' f_X(x) \delta(a(x-x')) dxdx' \\
\end{align}
Now here the $a$ on right will cancel out with $a$ from the delta function, if it didn't I get the usual formula from least squares optimization. Is there a mistake in this?
